# How to get data for ACADEMIC + SPOKEN (Academic speech) simultaneously using BNC?

Tags: corpora

[image: BNC Interface]

I'm looking for filler words used in academia. Since fillers are mainly used in spoken discourse, I need to look for **academic spoken** 'texts'. Anyone knows how to do this using BNC?

(Explanation: If I go to Section 1 and select *Academic*, then the results include both written and spoken. If I choose in Section 2-->*Spoken*, then the results show two tables in order to compare them. I need both these two features in one.)

Your help would be much appreciated. :)